# X11/Cocoa Custom Looks?

Tags: windows, linux, cocoa, macos, x11

Do the X11/Cocoa frameworks allow for custom windows like how Windows does? What I mean is, do they allow for the custom shape, like how some game launchers do, or for custom animations, title bars, etc?

Comment: Since you speak of "Cocoa framework", you should add the "Apple" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X11 and Cocoa are very different things. But yes, [X11 supports shaped windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_extension) and with a compositor running you can do nifty things using RGBA visuals: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHZfH1Qhonk

Answer (score 1):

It sure does.  You can subclass or modify just about every UI element available in some shape or form.  For example, take at look at the BWToolkit: http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11

You mention X11, usually used for Unix [based S.O. (s) ]. Gnome & KDE interfaces are "wrappers" for X11 running, usually, on Linux, and doing the features you mention.

You mention Cocoa, then its Mac, you forgot to add the tag.